# CSS Scroll Animation won't run in django

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, django

I'm using Django, and Jquery to fade in an image when it shows on screen in my browser. I'm trying to avoid using external libraries and I found a good tutorial.

The thing is, the code works on codepen but not in my Django website.

This is the codepen http://codepen.io/SitePoint/pen/MwEaQM

And this is my code:

html

```
{% load staticfiles %}

<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-2.1.0.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/modernizr/modernizr-2.7.2.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/animate.css' %}">
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/animate.js' %}"></script>

<body>
<!--For our animations to look good, the animated elements need to be able to be scrolled to. For this example I've added dummy content to the top -->
<div class="main-container">
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Slide in from the left </h1>
    <p>This animation will focus on sliding an element from the left once it enters the view of the user</p>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <h2>
 Our Testimonials <i class="fa fa-comment"></i></h2>
    <p> We have worked in the industry for 15 years and have provided services to a wide range of clients.</p>
    <p>Come and see what our clients are saying about our services. </p>
  </div>
  <div class="container cf">
    <!-- testimonial one -->
    <div class="animation-element slide-left testimonial">
      <div class="header">
        <div class="left">
          <img src="http://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0B7UPM0QugWUjVTdZcktRTWhNamM" />
        </div>
        <div class="right">
          <h3>Johnathon Richard Smith</h3>
          <h4>CEO / Manager - Auto Incorporated</h4>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="content"><i class="fa fa-quote-left"></i> When I started using their service I was skeptical. They promised me a 300% return on my initial investment. However they came through on their word and now my business is flourishing.. <i class="fa fa-quote-right"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="rating">
        <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-star-half-o"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--testimonial two -->
    <div class="animation-element slide-left testimonial">
      <div class="header">
        <div class="left">
          <img src="http://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0B7UPM0QugWUjV3BseTMtcEU1T2M" />
        </div>
        <div class="right">
          <h3>Joanna Hammerlton</h3>
          <h4>Marketing Manager - Omega Creative</h4>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="content"><i class="fa fa-quote-left"></i> Our company first enlisted their services when we had a down-turn in sales and revene. They outlined a series of steps we could take to improve our position and within a year we are making signifcant improvements..
        <i class="fa fa-quote-right"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="rating">
        <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-star-o"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--testimonial three -->
    <div class="animation-element slide-left testimonial">
      <div class="header">
        <div class="left">
          <img src="http://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0B7UPM0QugWUjTURta0pyMEtoUmc
" />
        </div>
        <div class="right">
          <h3>Mark Jamerson</h3>
          <h4>CEO - Generic Business</h4>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="content"><i class="fa fa-quote-left"></i> We entered into a 12 month period of service with this company in the hopes to improve our returns. After this period we have a return of double our initial investment..
        <i class="fa fa-quote-right"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="rating">
        <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--testimonial four -->
    <div class="animation-element slide-left testimonial">
      <div class="header">
        <div class="left">
          <img src="http://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0B7UPM0QugWUjb1dxcGZEYUc0Z3M" />
        </div>
        <div class="right">
          <h3>Susan Hilton</h3>
          <h4>Financial Officer - People Tech</h4>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="content"><i class="fa fa-quote-left"></i> Our involvement in this company has been mutually beneficial. We were hoping for slightly higher returns, however the current level of returns are sufficient..
        <i class="fa fa-quote-right"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="rating">
        <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-star-o"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-star-o"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

css

```
/*These styles contain basic styles for fomatting along with our animation css*/

body {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  background: #efefef;
  line-height: 170%;
}

strong,
b {
  font-weight: 600
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 150%;
}

i.fa {
  color: #333;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}
/*clearfixes*/

.cf:before,
.cf:after {
  content: " ";
  display: table;
}

.cf:after {
  clear: both;
}

.main-container {
  background: #fff;
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: 25px auto 25px auto;
  position: relative;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  padding: 25px;
}
/*animation element*/

.animation-element {
  opacity: 0;
  position: relative;
}
/*animation element sliding left*/

.animation-element.slide-left {
  opacity: 0;
  -moz-transition: all 500ms linear;
  -webkit-transition: all 500ms linear;
  -o-transition: all 500ms linear;
  transition: all 500ms linear;
  -moz-transform: translate3d(-100px, 0px, 0px);
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(-100px, 0px, 0px);
  -o-transform: translate(-100px, 0px);
  -ms-transform: translate(-100px, 0px);
  transform: translate3d(-100px, 0px, 0px);
}

.animation-element.slide-left.in-view {
  opacity: 1;
  -moz-transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
  -o-transform: translate(0px, 0px);
  -ms-transform: translate(0px, 0px);
  transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
}
/*animation slide left styled for testimonials*/

.animation-element.slide-left.testimonial {
  float: left;
  width: 47%;
  margin: 0% 1.5% 3% 1.5%;
  background: #F5F5F5;
  padding: 15px;
box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border: solid 1px #EAEAEA;
}
.animation-element.slide-left.testimonial:hover,
.animation-element.slide-left.testimonial:active{
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 8px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}

.animation-element.slide-left.testimonial:nth-of-type(odd) {
  width: 48.5%;
  margin: 0% 1.5% 3.0% 0%;
}

.animation-element.slide-left.testimonial:nth-of-type(even) {
  width: 48.5%;
  margin: 0% 0% 3.0% 1.5%;
}

.animation-element.slide-left.testimonial .header{
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.animation-element.slide-left.testimonial .left{
  float: left;
  margin-right: 15px;
}
.animation-element.slide-left.testimonial .right{
  float: left;
}

.animation-element.slide-left.testimonial img {
  width: 65px;
  height: 65px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.5);
}

.animation-element.slide-left.testimonial h3 {
  margin: 0px 0px 5px 0px;
}

.animation-element.slide-left.testimonial h4 {
  margin: 0px 0px 5px 0px;
}

.animation-element.slide-left.testimonial .content {
  float: left;
  width:100%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.animation-element.slide-left.testimonial .rating{}

.animation-element.slide-left.testimonial i {
  color: #aaa;
  margin-right: 5px;
}



/*media queries for small devices*/
@media screen and (max-width: 678px){
  /*testimonials*/
  .animation-element.slide-left.testimonial,
  .animation-element.slide-left.testimonial:nth-of-type(odd),
  .animation-element.slide-left.testimonial:nth-of-type(even){
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px 0px 20px 0px;
  }
  .animation-element.slide-left.testimonial .right,
  .animation-element.slide-left.testimonial .left,
  .animation-element.slide-left.testimonial .content,
  .animation-element.slide-left.testimonial .rating{
    text-align: center;
    float: none;
  }
  .animation-element.slide-left.testimonial img{
    width: 85px;
    height: 85px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
  }

}
```

js

```
var $animation_elements = $('.animation-element');
var $window = $(window);

function check_if_in_view() {
  var window_height = $window.height();
  var window_top_position = $window.scrollTop();
  var window_bottom_position = (window_top_position + window_height);

  $.each($animation_elements, function() {
    var $element = $(this);
    var element_height = $element.outerHeight();
    var element_top_position = $element.offset().top;
    var element_bottom_position = (element_top_position + element_height);

    //check to see if this current container is within viewport
    if ((element_bottom_position >= window_top_position) &&
        (element_top_position <= window_bottom_position)) {
      $element.addClass('in-view');
    } else {
      $element.removeClass('in-view');
    }
  });
}

$window.on('scroll resize', check_if_in_view);
$window.trigger('scroll');
```

It should be the same. I'm not sure why it won't work. I've tried wrapping the jquery in a function to make it wait for the content to load but I got the same result.

EDIT: [Here is a screenshot of the requests](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jwGPO.png) It seems to be loading everything fine. There are no errors. The animated content is hidden as it should but it does not appear when I scroll.

Comment: You may check about you django settings.py to ensure your media path is set properly.Or are you using nginx, If so, you have to set nginx.conf too.

Answer (score 0):

Are there any errors? Are the CSS and JS files present? This should not have anything to do with Django directly, but could be due to the files not being served correctly using Django's static files engine. Are you sure all files are being downloaded?

Comment: It seems to be loading everything fine. There are no errors. The animated content is hidden as it should but it does not appear when I scroll.

I added a screenshot of the GET requests in the console when I load the website.